# validation on android textbox

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` where the user should put a IP address like **192.168.21.212**. How to add validation for this? I tried

`android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

but it allows only one .(dot). How to make it allow three dots?

Comment: you need to check how much `'.'` are in string using charat in for loop else you take 4 editText with characterSize of 3...

Comment: android:inputType="number" is enough.

Comment: @vsk number don't allow dot.

Comment: @SilentKiller edittext allowing character and symbols

Comment: @bumba tried out the codes given below as answers... if it is useful to you.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your EditText in the xml, add `android:digits="0123456789.,! etc"`

Comment: No he was fast sorry year I already accepted that ans but I don't understand why some one down voted me

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ip_ed_txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache Commons [InetAddressValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html#line.34) class which has a [isValidInet4Address(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html#line.71)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Textwatcher` for that textview object. You can handle the each key input through the

> TextWatcher

interface.

There is no inputType for IP address validation in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own InputFilter: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html

```
EditText text = new EditText(this);
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
                if (!resultingTxt.matches ("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) { 
                    return "";
                } else {
                    String[] splits = resultingTxt.split("\\.");
                    for (int i=0; i<splits.length; i++) {
                        if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
        }
    };
    text.setFilters(filters);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check it in the code when the user submit the edittext.

maye something like this?:

```
public boolean DotValidator(String text) {
    int anumOfDots = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == '.') {
            anumOfDots++;
        }
    }
    if (anumOfDots == 3) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will validate a lot of wrong IP addresses (e.g., 1..2.3, 1000.2000.3000.3, and so on). Checking the presence of three dots is not the right way to validate an IP address.

Comment: yep it is but you can easily change the code to check the number of characters between the dots

Comment: And check that each number is in the right range, and check that the IP is valid (not all the tuples are valid) and so on.

Comment: exactly, but I understood his question as if he wanted to validate just by looking that there were 3 dots

Answer (score 0):

**IP Address Validator**

```
private static final String PATTERN = 
    "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
    "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

public static boolean validate(final String ip){          
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
  return matcher.matches();             
}
```